# How to make a List[String] to be a list of strings

Tags: scala

I have an Option[List[String]] where I have several fields and want to create an object with them as parameters. Is there a way of doing this other than manually?

Details:

```
class Foo(var1: String, var2: String, var3: String)
```

I can't do

```
foo = new Foo(datarow)
```

And would rather not do

```
foo = new Foo(datarow.get(0), datarow.get(1), datarow.get(2))
```

Comment: What should happen if the `Option` is `None`; and if the list has more or less than 3 elements?

Comment: I have the same questions as Aleksey. Also, couldn't you use something like val (var1, var2, var3) = datarow.take(3) // I am ignoring the Option as you can unpack the list with pattern matching.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a safe way to do this that's still pretty concise:

```
class Foo(var1: String, var2: String, var3: String)

val datarow = Option(List("a", "b", "c"))

val result: Option[Foo] = datarow.collect {
  case v1 :: v2 :: v3 :: _ => new Foo(v1, v2, v3)
}
```

The combination of `collect` and pattern matching on the first three elements of the list says "if this `Option` isn't empty and if it contains a list with at least three elements, use them to instantiate the `Foo`".

You end up with an `Option[Foo]`, not a `Foo`, but that's a small price to pay to avoid runtime errors because the `Option` is empty or the list doesn't have enough elements.

Comment: Thanks, this isn't exactly what I was looking for but still a very solid and probably the best solution.